# Additional params in nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have nested resources:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

My current `link_to` is this:

```
<%= link_to 'Reply', [:new, @post, :comment] %>
```

Resulting in:

```
http://example.com/posts/8/comments/new
```

But I need a link like this:

```
http://example.com/posts/8/comments/new?parent_id=7
```

How can I use `link_to` to create that link?

Comment: try `new_post_comment_path(@post, :parent_id => 7)`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it with a single match statement:

```
match "(/bazess/:baz_id)(/foos/:foo_id)/bars(/page/:page)(/:format)" => "bars#index", :as => :bars
```

You can also refer to [this article on nested resources from The Rails 3 Way](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671632&seqNum=7).

Comment: How does this address the question? OP is asking how to create a link, not route it.

Answer (score 1):

Posted as answer after my comment:

```
new_post_comment_path(@post, :parent_id => 7)
```